# Check if an array of strings contains a substring of a given string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following string:

```
var teststring = "Hello"
```

I have the following array of strings:

```
var listofstrings = ["Hellothere", "Welcome", "Helloworld", "Some String"];
```

I want to have inside of a conditional, a simple check to return if any thing in 'listofstrings' matches any part of 'teststring'. The following is the pseudocode:

```
if(teststring.indexOf(any-part-of-listofstrings) > -1)
```

How can I accomplish this? The simplest way I can think of is for looping it, but am looking to see if there is a better way.

By for looping, I mean multiple lines like:

```
for(var i = 0; i < listofstrings.length; i++) {
    if(teststring.indexOf(listofstrings[i] > -1) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

The above takes up multiple lines seems too complex for what I am trying to do...

Comment: @Dan that question does not address my question. The answer in that question requires an exact match to the entire string. If you modified the example in answer to ["I", "like", "turtles love me"], then it breaks and returns false. I want to return true in that case because turtles was part of the substring of at least one of the items in the array.

Comment: This is not built into JavaScript. You will have to write a function to do this yourself.

Comment: The question is not a duplicate of the suggested link. Please don't vote to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Array#some`, and to make things shorter, use an arrow function and `String#includes` instead of `String#indexOf`:

```
if(listofstrings.some(str => teststring.includes(str))) {
    // found one
}
```

Comment: This is shorter and less complex than a for loop for sure. If anyone has even better/shorter ways of doing this, please share. Perhaps someday, Javascript will have some built in function to handle this.